# ASPEED AST2050 not responding to IPMI Get Channel Cipher Suites

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I have a Quanta QSSC-890 in a remote location which supposedly supports IPMI version 2.0 but does not send a response when I issue unauthenticated `Get Channel Cipher Suites` command.

The problem is that I work on a project where I have to use a Java IPMI lib (from Verax Systems), which has an internal state machine that forces me to issue `Get Channel Cipher Suites` first so that it does a transition to a usable state.

Also, when I issue `ipmi -I lanplus -H ... lan print 1 -v`
I get all the info except for
`Get LAN Parameter 'RMCP+ Cipher Suite Count' command failed: Unknown (0x80)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the IPMI 2.0 spec that mandates the "Get Channel Cipher Suite" works during an unauthenticated RMCP session. The Quanta and also HP iLO version 2.0 respond to the command only within authenticated RMCP sessions.

It is not a problem with Verax, the Java Hemi IPMI libraries have the same issue.